# Extracting data from a meta tag beautifulsoup returning null

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, meta

I trying to scrape the mileage of a car from this website
https://cazana.com/uk/car/RA51GZJ

The data I want is the mileage (128,375 miles) 
when i try to scrape this page i get nothing returned 
I orignally tried to scape the body of the page with no luck

```
url = "https://cazana.com/uk/car/RA51GZJ"
page2 = requests.get(url)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup2.findAll('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'})

print (result)
```

Returns []

This is the html file

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="RA51GZJ - 2001 NISSAN ALMERA. Colour silver, 128,375 miles, 3 previous owners. Registered in Reading. Tax, MOT &amp; Vehicle history check available.">
```

Thanks

Comment: does `page2` have any content?

Comment: I believe so I used code similar to this on other websites and it worked but on this particular website I'm having issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is unsuccessful, which is why you're not finding the right tag.
The returned content is an error page.
 You can bypass this error by changing your `User-Agent` header to that of a browser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://cazana.com/uk/car/RA51GZJ'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
    'Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'
}

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
match = soup.find('meta', name='description')

if match:
    print(match.attrs['content'])
else:
    print('Request unsuccessful')
```

Note that too many requests at once can also trigger an unsuccessful request.

Comment: I get this error when i try this code AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Comment: Yes, that's because your request is being rejected. You could try again after a while, or use an `if match:` to let you know that it's not working.

Comment: It works for me, but not when I use the script several times at once. There's no other solution to this, I'm afraid ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I will ask a friend to try as maybe I have requested the site too much today

Comment: Shall i change Linux x86_64 to Windows x86_64 as I am on windows 10

Comment: It shouldn't matter. A request is a request, no matter what browser you're using.